# The Right Way To Draw Normals In OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, opengl, normals

Right now I am writing a program in OpenGl. I'm rendering some-what complex 3D figures from files. After triple checking the code, I know that all the values are being read right. The only thing thats acting weird is the normals. I'm drawing them like this:

```
     glVertex3fv(vert1);
     glVertex3fv(vert2);
     glVertex3fv(vert3);


    glNormal3fv(norm1);
    glNormal3fv(norm2);
    glNormal3fv(norm3);
```

The values are being read from GLFloats. Tell me the right way, or at least what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `glVertex`, that finishes a vertex, so you need to set all the other vertex state before that. You need to set the normal for a vertex before finishing it.

It should look like this:

```
glNormal3fv(norm1);
glVertex3fv(vert1);

glNormal3fv(norm2);
glVertex3fv(vert2);

glNormal3fv(norm3);
glVertex3fv(vert3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing, would you have any Idea why this is happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229110/normals-acting-weird-in-opengl